# what is a transaction in Azure's cognitive Services text analytics API

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-service, azure-cognitive-services

I am looking at this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

and would like to test drive the Free - Web/Container to perform some sentiment analysis. It says that 5000 transactions are free. I understand that a record equals 1000 characters but what is a a transaction? Is it a text blob with potentially more than 1000 characters? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For the free tier, 1 transaction = 1 call to 1 method of the API, whatever the length of the text used in the query. There is no notion of text record here.

When you have a doubt, use the calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?service=cognitive-services